# Несколько однотипных записать одной регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть код:

```
$a[0]=preg_replace('/Для(\s)/u','для$1',$a[0]);
$a[0]=preg_replace('/И(\s)/u','и$1',$a[0]);
$a[0]=preg_replace('/Или(\s)/u','или$1',$a[0]);
$a[0]=preg_replace('/На(\s)/u','на$1',$a[0]);
```

Суть этого кода в том что он в строке текста у междометий опускает первую букву в нижний регистр. Строка такая, что все слова в ней начинаются с большой буквы.

Как-то бы так записать, но это неправильно:

```
$a[0]=preg_replace('/(На|Для|Или|И)(\s)/u','DownCase($1)$2',$a[0]);
```

голову ломаю..

Comment: А зачем регулярки, почему бы не:

    echo str_replace(
        array('Для', 'Или', 'И', 'На'),
        array('для', 'или', 'и', 'на'),
        'Для Или И На'
    );

Comment: ну да.. тоже прекрасный вариант, он будет даже быстрее работать, но повторение междометий некрасиво, а так тоже бы плюсанул

Comment: В этом варианте закралась ошибка. Если будет например слово Нальчик или Начальник, то у него регистр тоже опуститься, а так ненадо =)

Comment: ну на самом деле оно просто решается, добавлением пробела в строку :)

Comment: Да в большинстве случаев междометия где-то перед пробелом, но с регулярками можно и в конце строки и перед восклЗнаком и Вопросительным и точкой и даже запятой..

Comment: Да, верно. Тогда регуляркой. Только лучше вместо `\s` использовать якорь `\b` с обоих сторон междометия. Если после него будет стоять знак препинания, а не пробельный символ то замена не сработает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a[0] = preg_replace("/(На|Для|Или|И)(\s)/ue",'mb_strtolower("$1", "UTF-8")."$2"', $a[0]);'
```

оно ?

Comment: Вот эта смесь нужных кавычек... Спасибо!